# Can't match a zero or more pattern in the middle

Tags: lua, match

In regex, you can use the regex expression `\d*` in the string

`"foo 123 bar"`

to match "123"

However, in lua, when you use the equivalent pattern `%d*` on the same string, you get *nothing*. Only when you use `%s%d*` will you get the correct match.

Why?

Comment: What lua function are you using to run the regex?

Comment: @Skully I am using string.match()

Comment: I think you don't understand what is going on here. the regex \d* is infinite. it will match 10 times. 9 empty strings and "123".  if your regex is setup to return after the first match you won't get "123" but an empty string. This is what happens in Lua. Lua returns the FIRST match, which is an empty string. if you'd start at character 5 string.match("foo 123 bar", "%d*", 5) you'll match "123" if you want to match a number it is non-sense to match zero or more digits. a number cannot consist of zero digits. match one more. https://regex101.com/r/bjfA3z/1  vs https://regex101.com/r/PPvIWw/1

Comment: Ah, this clarifies everything, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to say that the behavior seems a bit weird to me. But it can be understood why the pattern matching in Lua is like that. As for `%d*`, Lua tried to match from beginning of your string, and matched a zero-length string.

```lua
local str = "foo 123 bar"
local result = str:match('%d*')
print(type(result), #result)
```

As you can see, it outputs `string  0`. It's not `nil`, so the matching is successful. That's how Lua interprets your pattern. When it comes to `%s%d*`, Lua cannot match a zero-length string, thus goes forward for  `123`.

To conclude, Lua won't look for a longer match even if it found a successful match the length of which is zero.

Comment: Compare with `for w in str:gmatch("%d*") do print(#w,w) end`.

Comment: Better yet, see the matching positions with `for p,w in str:gmatch("()(%d*)") do print(p,#w,w) end`.

Answer (score 3):

To match zero or more digits in [Lua regex](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) you can use the expression `%d+`.

- `%d` Match any digit character.
- `+` Match 1 or more repetitions.

```lua
local str = "foo 123 bar"
print(str:match("%d+")) -- Outputs '123'.
```

Comment: Thanks, that really does work. Could you give any form of clarifications as to why "zero or more" works with regex while on lua it doesn't? Anything that you put behind the "[character]*" expression makes it not match. Weird.

Comment: please see my comment above. \d* is not equivalent to %d+